# How to check my code style in the following way

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, tslint

You can help to see if you can do some code style checks such as tslint during yarn build

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is this here supposed to be? A question?

Answer (score 0):

> such as tslint during yarn build

Add a `prebuild` script target. Any `prefoo` script would run if you run `yarn foo`. Same for `build`